# Eureka - How to pass values from collection to form

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Im new to Eureka and have my swift project where I want to pass to an alert element a collection instead of hardcoded values.

Here is my actual code:

```
 <<< AlertRow<String>() {
                $0.title = "Employee Type"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Employee Type"
                $0.options = ["ADMIN","WORKER","HR","PR"]
                }.onChange { row in
                    print(row.value)
                }
            }
```

So, instead of hardcoded options I want to pass an array of a class that I have:

This is my class:

```
class EmployeeType : AnyObject {

    var typeId : Int = 0
    var description : String = ""

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you declare an array with strings:

```
let emplyeeTypeDescriptions = [String]()
```

then you fill this array with the (localized) descriptions

Then you fill the form:

```
<<< AlertRow<String>() {
            $0.title = "Employee Type"
            $0.selectorTitle = "Employee Type"
            $0.options = model.emplyeeTypeDescriptions
            }.onChange { row in
                print(row.value)
            }
        }
```

(if you want to change the options while your controller is showing, that's a different question)

Comment: What if instead of array of strings I have a class with Id and Description? And I want to get the Id on the onChange event?

Comment: In row.value you get one String. So your model must be able to find the correct instance of your class for that string.

Comment: yes that make sense. I just worried about when you have same values but different Id's.

Comment: Yes, the options have to be distinct.

Comment: I found the way of passing an array of object. It works nice in AlertRow but in PushRow I get an error Duplicate Tag.